# ¿Cómo mantenerme en la ventana de origen con selenium c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hola estoy trabajando con selenium web driver en c#, con lo cual estoy construyendo un API, estoy dividiendo el scraper por funciones, el problema que estoy enfrentando es que cada vez que mando a traer la función me abre una página en blanco/ventana(data;,) lo cual me quita el control de la página de origen y no puedo dirigirme a ella.

Estoy intentado hacer un recorrido de las páginas que tengo abierta sin embargo solo me devuelve la página en blanco ya mencionada.

```
            ReadOnlyCollection<string> WindowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
            string browserTitle = "";
            string browserPageSource = "";
            string browserURL = "";
            foreach (string item in WindowHandles)
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Window(item);
                browserTitle = driver.Title;
                browserPageSource = driver.PageSource;
                browserURL = driver.Url;
            }
```

¿Cómo puedo manterme sobre la página de origen y evitar que se abran páginas en blanco?

Answer (score 0):

El código que pasas no me cuadra con lo que estás diciendo que te da problema. Si te aparecen ventanas en blanco con "data" en el campo dirección es que estás abriendo diferentes driver en lugar de mantener el que abres.
¿Puedes pasar el código en el que usas el driver o en el que declaras el driver para ver si está ahí el problema de que te aparezcan tantas ventanas en blanco?
Un saludo.